# Scroll long list to place the div on the top of the page

Tags: html, css

[image]

I have set the right div to be scrollable by setting following css.

```
.map-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 80vh;
  display: "flex";
}
```

Now when Home 3 is clicked I want the scroll to auto scroll and display Home 3 in the block where home 1 is displaying. Just scrolling home3 up and showing in top of scroll div.

Comment: Can you share all of your code(html, css) to help us understand your problem better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set different `id`s to each `.map-container` on the right side and use `a` tags on the left buttons.

Left side:

```html
...
<a href="#home1">Home 1 </a>
<a href="#home2">Home 2 </a>
<a href="#home3">Home 3 </a>
...
```

Right side:

```html
...
<div id="home1" class="map-container> ... </div>
<div id="home2" class="map-container> ... </div>
<div id="home3" class="map-container> ... </div>
...
```

Refer to [a tag: Linking to an element on the same page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#linking_to_an_element_on_the_same_page) for more information.

Comment: dont forget to add `scroll-behavior: smooth` to the right side did so it actually scrolls and not jumps.